# Print value in SQL depending on its presence in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table of the form

```
Col1  | Col2
-------------
A     |   C
B     |   A
C     |   X
D     |   A
E     |   NULL
```

If any element of Col1 is present in Col2, then It should be printed as 
Element, YES.

If it is not present in Col2, then it needs to be printed as element, NO and if corresponding col2 value is NULL then it needs to be printed as element, NULL

So final output should look like

```
A YES
B NO
C YES
D NO
E NULL
```

I was able to write three individual queries for the same but am struggling with the moment on how to put them inside Case statements in SQL.

```
SELECT Col1 FROM table WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM table)

Select col1 FROM table where Col2 is NULL

SELECT Col1 FROM table WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col2 FROM table)
```

I tried putting them inside case statements

```
Select col1, Case
when (SELECT Col1 FROM table WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM table))
then "YES"
when (Select col1 FROM table where Col2 is NULL)
then "NULL"
else
"NO"
```

But I was getting an error. How should I fix this?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the query to look like this:

```
select col1,
       (case when col2 is null then NULL
             when col1 in (select t2.col2 from t t2)
             then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end)
from t;
```